# ～てない - ambiguity between ている and てある

Tags: grammar

> 手を上げてない人は私だけです。

上げてない is the negative form of てある  right? Most people would omit the い in ている. So for me it is hard to differentiate if てある or ている is used since both sounds the same (negative only). So how to differentiate? From writing the ている is ていない and てある is てない. In writing you can't omit the い in ている／ていない right?

手をあげていない means: not raising hand.
手をあげてない means: hand has not been raised.

Are these correct? Is the meaning of the first sentence like this? the person whose hand has not (yet) been raised is only me. Which can be simplified into : the person who is not raising their hand is me. If I change ない into いない... Then it would roughly translate as (hand is still rising ; still in motion ; not yet been raised) right? Because in english "raising our hand" usually means the state after the action of "raise" is completed (hand is constant in the air and not going any higher). Unlike "falling" that usually means the ongoing action of "fall" and not the state after the action of "fall" is completed. Feel free to correct any facts conveyed here.

Comment: How do you differentiate `has` and `is` in `he's finished`?

Comment: It depends on the context. Subject + has + V3(past participle) + object. Eg. Tom has cleaned the room. He has finished (the project). Object(as subject) + verb to be + V3(past participle) + with/by + (). Eg. Tom is invited by John. He is finished (with the project). In general : 'He is finished' implies that someone do the verb 'finish' with 'He' as the object. In this expression, the subject is himself. The final state after the verb is done is described by 'he is finished'. He finishes himself. 'He has finished' implies that 'he' is the subject and has already reach that state of completion.

Comment: You have your answer then?

Comment: `上げてない is the negative form of てある right?` -> No, 手をあげてない is a contraction of あげて**い**ない, and is a the negative of あげている/あげてる.   `手をあげていない means: not raising hand.
手をあげてない means: hand has not been raised.` -> These mean the same thing. あげてない is a contraction of あげていない. And it can mean either a continuous action "am not raising (now)" or present perfective "haven't raised" (or past "didn't raise")

Comment: 例文を、↓サザーランドさんの使っている「置いてない」みたいなのにした方がいいかもしれません。。「置いてない」（＝「置いていません」「置いてありません」）なら、「置いている」と「置いてある」の両方の否定形になるので。。他には、「買ってない」（＝「買っていません」「買ってありません」）→「買っている」「買ってある」とか、「書いてない」、「言ってない」、「渡してない」、「考えてない」とか・・・

Comment: Does this mean that ~てない of ~てある does not exist? So ~てない is always the negative of ~ている and never the negative of ~てある?

Answer (score -1):

Generally I think you can tell by the subject.
(Very similar to the conversation between yourself and oldergod above)

上げてる (who or what?) ⇒　私 ＝ 上げて**い**る

Other examples of ambiguity resolved by identifying the subject/actor:

> 置いてない

- 「私はそこに置いてないよ」 - Subject/Actor is 私, so this must mean 置いて**いない**
- 「お肉は冷蔵庫に置いてると思う」 - Subject is probably お肉, so this must mean 置いて**ありません**

> 開けてない

- 「私は窓開けてないよ」 - Subject/Actor is 私, so this must mean 開けて**いない**
- 「窓は開けてないと思う」 - Subject is probably 窓, so this must mean 開けて**ありません**

Comment: I would appreciate corrective criticism when receiving a down vote, thanks!

Comment: I did not downvote this, but there is at least one error in that 上げてある (assuming that is even possible) would never be contracted to 上げてる, so your topmost example doesn't illustrate anything very well.